# Change text of UIlabel in static cells

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I create a `UITableView` with option content to Static Cells in the Editor. I would like to translate some words with `LocalizedString` but the UILabel text didn't change. I do this :

the UIlabel boulet belong to a cell in the section of the `UITabeView`
***.h***

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel*  labelToken
```

***.m***

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.labelToken); // => OUTPUT (null)
    self.labelToken.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ :", NSLocalizedString(@"TOKEN", nil)];

}
```

Comment: You have to also connect the label to the IBOutlet through the interface builder

Comment: Yes with CTRL + DRAG TO .H file and named labelToken

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you do your text assignment in `viewWillAppear:` instead?

Comment: @Kamaros yes same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. When **i clicked on Localized** on the `StoryBaord`, **it has generate 3 sub files of Storyboard my (fr, zn, cn)**.My solution it's to **delete the Storyboard** and restoring from a versioning software.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *labelToken;
@end

////Implementation File
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self.labelToken setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"HELLO", @"HELLO")]];
}

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

/////
You have to link labeltoken outlet to static cell's label in storyboard.

Comment: like i said up "Yes with CTRL + DRAG TO .H file and named labelToken".

Answer (score 0):

Can change text of UIlabel in static cells with below method well.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```